# How to block requests to server with user name / password?

Tags: url, http-headers, redirect

We have realized that this URL `http://Keyword:redacted@example.com/` redirects to `http://example.com/` when copied and pasted into the browser's address bar.

As far as I understand this might be used in some ftp connections but we have no such use on our website. We are suspecting that we are targeted by an attack and have been warned by Google that we are passing PII (mostly email addresses) in our URL requests to their Google Adsense network. We have not been able to find the source, but we have been warned that the violation is in the form of `http://Keyword:redacted@example.com/`

*How can we stop this from happening?*
*What URL redirect method we can use to not accept this and return an error message?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I experienced a similar issue for a client website and followed up with Adsense support.  The matter was escalated to a specialist team who investigated and determined that flagged violations with the format `http://Keyword:redacted@example.com/` will be considered false positives.  I'm not sure if this applies to all publishers or was specific to our case, but it might be worth following up with Adsense support.

Comment: That's what we did in the end as well. Thank you, it is good to know we are not alone!

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do. This is handled entirely by your browser long before it even thinks about "talking" to your server.

That's a strange URL for people to copy/paste into the browser's address bar unless they have been told/trained to do so. Your best bet is to tell them to STOP IT! :-)

I suppose you could look at the HTTP Authorization Headers and report an error if they come in populated... (This would `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` in PHP.) I've never looked at these values when the header doesn't request them, so I'm not sure if it would work or not...

Comment: The problem is, we have received a warning from Google Adsense telling us people are accessing our website like this, and we are passing PII through this. I am just trying to make sure we don't pass PII to Google in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `http://abc:def@something.com` means you're sending userid='abc', password='def' as basic authentication parameters.  Your browser will pull out the userid & password and send them along as authentication information, leaving the url without them.

As Peter Bowers mentioned, you could check the authorization headers and see if they're coming in that way, but you can't stop others from doing it if they want.  If it happens a lot then I'd suspect that somewhere there's a web form asking users to enter their user/password and it's getting encoded that way.  One way to sleuth it out would be to see if you can identify someone by the userid specified.

Having `Keyword:redacted` sounds odd.  It's possible Google Adsense changed the values to avoid including confidential info.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, Google has indeed changed them. We are being warned that we pass confidential info to them in the format I provided, but we cannot figure out how it might been happening.

Comment: How are these url's getting to Google? A url pasted into a browser will cause that server (not Google's) to receive the request. If the resulting web page hooks into Adsense then perhaps that is being done incorrectly and is passing along extra information that it shouldn't.  If it's your web page that Google is concerned about, you should check your PHP (or whatever code is generating the response) to see what it's sending to Google Adsense.

Comment: That is what is puzzling us. We had a warning from Google Adsense team and they said the URL: http://Keyword:redacted@example.com/ was passing them PII. We do not even have a membership scheme let alone any services like FTP and it does not any sense to receive anything like this from our visitors anyway. I contacted Google for more information but have not heard anything back.